# Finding the speed of a person

Tags: algebra-precalculus

After hours of struggling I'm posting it here. I hope someone will solve it.

> David and Jess start at the same time from points $A$ and $B$ and travel towards $B$ and $A$ respectively. After they meet, David takes $40$ minutes to reach $B$ and Jess takes $1.5$ hours to reach $A$. If David's speed is $36$ km/h, what is Jess's speed?

My Work:
if two people P and Q start at the same same time from A and B, after crossing each other they take X and Y seconds to reach B and A then P's speed : Q's speed = squareroot(y) : squareroot(x). i.e squareroot(1.5*60):squareroot(40) which is 3:2. so Jess's speed 36*2/3= 24Kmph. But i dont understand how P's speed : Q's speed = squareroot(y) : squareroot(x).

Comment: How did you come up with "P's speed : Q's speed = squareroot(y) : squareroot(x)"? And if you came up with it yourself, why do you say you don't understand it? Or is this the solution you saw somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_D$ be Dave's speed, and $S_J$ be Jess's. Say they meet at time $t$ at distance $d_1$ from $A$ and $d_2$ from $B$. We can write $t=d_1/S_D$  and $t = d_2/S_J$ and combine them into
$$\frac{d_1}{d_2} = \frac{S_D}{S_J}.$$

On the latter part of the journey, 
we can write similar equations $40=d_2/S_D$ and $90=d_1/S_J$ and combine these into

$$\frac{d_1}{d_2} = \frac{90S_J}{40S_D}.$$

Combining this with the equation above we get

$$90S_J^2 = 40S_D^2,$$

or
$$S_J = \frac23 S_D.$$

$S_D = 36/60$ km/minute so $S_J=24/60$ km/minute, or $24$ kph.

Comment: Your units are not correct. $90S_J$ and $40S_D$ are not the distances as your time is in min. but the velocity is in km/*hr*. This throws off your answer.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life, thanks for spotting that. The ratios of the quantities doesn't change, though.

Comment: Yes, I just finished checking that for myself and was about to say something. Units always kill. I hated when my Physics professors drilled them into us but now I'm thankful. It makes doing applied problems so much easier to have units as a check/guide. In any case, great solution! +1

Comment: That was a awesome solution. Thx

Answer (score -2):

David needs x+2/3 hours at 36 km/h, so the full distance is 36*(x+2/3) km, right?
Jess needs x+3/2 hours for the 36*(x+2/3) km, so he travels 36*(x+2/3)/(x+3/2).

David will need x hours for 36x km
Jess will need x hours for 36*(x+2/3)/(x+3/2) km.

So the full distance is 36x+36*(x+2/3)/(x+3/2).

36*(x+2/3) = 36x+36*(x+2/3)/(x+3/2)

or shorter

(x+2/3) = x+(x+2/3)/(x+3/2)

which then is

```
2/3 = (x+2/3)/(x+3/2)
(x+3/2)*2/3 = (x+2/3)
2x/3+1 = x+2/3
2x/3-x = 2/3-1
x = 1
```

Quod errat demonstrator.

Comment: Quod erat demonstrandum ;)!

Comment: Is your space–time continuum broken or did you overlook "David and Jess start at the same time from points A and B". (You could only argue that they may not be travelling at average speed before they meet, because this is what is not given. Without that assumption, you can't solve this question.) EDIT: Dreamer did remove his comment that I answered upon. Seems he found the error before I pointed it out.

Comment: They started at the same time from points A and B. please see my work in the question.

Comment: In your second sentence, $36(x+2/3)/(x+3/2)$ is Jess' speed, not the distance he traveled. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting you.

Comment: Why would someone vote down that clear and crisp answer of mine? Did I oversimplify things?

Comment: Indeed, $x+2/3$ and $x+3/2$ both have units of hours and cancel leaving only $36$ which has units of km/h. So $36(x+2/3)/(x+3/2)$ is a speed not a distance. There are therefore errors in your solution.

Comment: At least in what you say. In the end, you are looking for Jess's speed.

Comment: I am not looking for Jess's speed, the original poster is.

Comment: @Alexander Im pretty sure it is a solvable question.

Comment: Indeed, but since you are attempting to answer his question, you are too. I agree with the solution, it's just the execution isn't the clearest.